# Selenium is slow after upgrading chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey All I have a question
today I upgrade my chrome driver.
chrome version 87.0.4280.66
chrome driver version: 87.0.4280.20

before the upgrade the tests took 20 minutes
after upgrade the tests are 3 hours.
I run them locally on my computer, and see that for example wait clickable is 10 times slower, send keys is also 10 times slower.
can someone advise?

Answer (score 0):

What chrome driver are you using? I cant find a chrome web driver version for google-chrome --version "87.0.4280.66"